# CSS Calendar alignments

Tags: html, css, calendar

I am new to CSS, building this calendar i made this, i need this calendar to fit into a JSP page.

1. This spans the whole page. can anyone suggest how to make resizable
2. Also when i have to make boxes empty to move the 1st of the month to
   the day of the week as the boxes move up and down. What can be done
   to fix that
3. Is there a better way to do this, need this a in this way with tool
   tip. Thanks for looking.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.month {
  padding: 70px 25px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.month ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.month ul li {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.month .prev {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.month .next {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.weekdays {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.weekdays li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 13.6%;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
}

.days {
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0;
}

.days li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 13.6%;
  height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  color: #777;
}

.days li .active {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #1abc9c;
  color: white !important
}


/* Add media queries for smaller screens */

@media screen and (max-width:720px) {
  .weekdays li,
  .days li {
    width: 13.1%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
  .weekdays li,
  .days li {
    width: 12.5%;
  }
  .days li .active {
    padding: 2px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 290px) {
  .weekdays li,
  .days li {
    width: 12.2%;
  }
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head/>

<body>

  <h1>CSS Calendar</h1>

  <div class="month">
    <ul>
      <li class="prev">&#10094;</li>
      <li class="next">&#10095;</li>
      <li style="text-align:center">
        August<br>
        <span style="font-size:18px">2016</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <ul class="weekdays">
    <li>Mo</li>
    <li>Tu</li>
    <li>We</li>
    <li>Th</li>
    <li>Fr</li>
    <li>Sa</li>
    <li>Su</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="days">
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li>1<br><br>$1.25
    </li>
    <li>2<br><br>$1.25
    </li>
    <li>3<br><br>$1.25
    </li>
    <li>4<br><br>$1.25
    </li>
    <li>5<br><br>$1.25
    </li>
    <li>6<br><br>$1.25
    </li>
    <li>7<br><br>$1.25
    </li>
    <li>8<br><br>$1.25
    </li>
    <li>9<br><br>$1.25
    </li>
    <li>10<br><br>$1.25
    </li>
    <li>11<br><br>$1.25
    </li>
    <li>12<br><br>$1.25
    </li>
    <li>13<br><br>$1.25
    </li>
    <li>14<br><br>$1.25
    </li>
    <li>15<br><br>$1.25
    </li>
    <li>16<br><br>$1.25
    </li>
    <li>17<br><br>$1.25
    </li>
    <li>18<br><br>$1.25
    </li>
    <li>19<br><br>$1.25
    </li>
    <li>20<br><br>$1.25
    </li>
    <li>21<br><br>$1.25
    </li>
    <li>22<br><br>$1.25
    </li>
    <li>23<br><br>$1.25
    </li>
    <li>24<br><br>$1.25
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tooltip">25<br><br>$1.25
        <span class="tooltiptext">Plan One:$1.25<br>Plan Two: $2.34</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tooltip">26<br><br>$1.25
        <span class="tooltiptext">Plan One:$1.25<br>Plan Two: $2.34</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tooltip">27<br><br>$1.25
        <span class="tooltiptext">Plan One:$1.25<br>Plan Two: $2.34</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tooltip">28<br><br>$1.25
        <span class="tooltiptext">Plan One:$1.25<br>Plan Two: $2.34</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tooltip">29<br><br>$1.25
        <span class="tooltiptext">Plan One:$1.25<br>Plan Two: $2.34</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tooltip">30<br><br>$1.25
        <span class="tooltiptext">Plan One:$1.25<br>Plan Two: $2.34</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tooltip">31<br><br>$1.25
        <span class="tooltiptext">Plan One:$1.25<br>Plan Two: $2.34</span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but &nbsp; didn't help much if you look at the result the empty first of the month day box is still misaligned with rest of the calendar. [link] https://jsfiddle.net/wdsLapz7/

Comment: To fix the box alignment, you can use `vertical-align: bottom` in `.days li` class so that bottom of the box is aligned to lowest box in the line.

Comment: Great Gaara can you also tell me about sizing the whole calendar as it occupies the whole page.

Comment: If you don't want your calendar to occupy whole page, you can put it in a container with specific width/height. https://jsfiddle.net/yxhgq1tz/2/

Comment: Great again but the it still sticks to the left of the page, is there way to size inside the middle of the page which looks like boxed calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what your are looking for.

1. Used `vertical-align: bottom` to fix the box alignment.
2. Horizontally centered the calendar in the page using `margin: 0 auto`.

https://jsfiddle.net/yxhgq1tz/3/

```
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

To center it vertically. there are couple of options.

1. Using css3 flexbox.
2. Using `vertical-align: middle` along with `display: table`

Comment: I tried what you suggested thanks again but Sun/Mon are wrapping into one